# $\mathbb{Z}_5$ as a subgroup of $S_5$ and the induced action on a vector space.

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, group-actions, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

I'm just trying to understand the following. Consider the cyclic group $(\mathbb{Z}_5,+)$ and the vector space $\mathbb{R}^5$.

*First Question*:

Can we say that $\mathbb{Z}_5 \le S_5$ (it is a subgroup of $S_5$ generated by the cycle $(01234))$ ?

And if yes, how to see that?

*Second Question*:

Also let's define an action by

\begin{align}
\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{R}^5 &\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^5\\
(g,\textbf{v}) &\mapsto g \cdot \textbf{v}:= (v_{g(1)}, v_{g(2)}, v_{g(3)},v_{g(4)}, v_{g(5)})
\end{align}

That is, we permute the coordinates of the vector $\textbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^5$. How many of those permutations we can find and why?

I think that the answer is $5$ because but I would like to be sure of why is that.
To define the above action, should I decide the dimension of the vector space accordingly to the number of elements in the group?

Many thanks,

James

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is *isomorphic to* a subgroup of $S_5$.  It can't be a subgroup because (a) the elements are different and (b) the operation is different.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: $(12345)$ generates a subgroup of order $5$ in $S_5$, which then must be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$. Note that $0\not\in X=\{1,2,\ldots ,n\}$, for $S_n={\rm Sym}(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

The action is not well-defined. For this, you need the setting

$g\cdot (v_1,\ldots,v_5) := (v_{g^{-1}(1)},\ldots,v_{g^{-1}(5)}).$

In this way, $(gh)\cdot v = g\cdot (h\cdot v)$ which does not hold in the above setting.

Comment: I disagree. It *is* well-defined. The problem is that it's not an action.

Comment: Why is it not an action? I have defined it to be a left action while the right counterpart would be $g^{-1}$ It's just a matter of convention isn'it?

Comment: @JamesArten $(gh \cdot \textbf{v})_{1} \ne (h \cdot \textbf{v})_{g(1)}$

Comment: but in general, if $x \mapsto g \cdot x$ is a left action, then $x \mapsto x \cdot g^{-1}$ is a right action and vice-versa, so doesn't this depend on how you define it?